# Linq SelectMany include parent

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, parent-child

I have the following three Linq To Sql entities: Location, Institution, and Building.

The Location table is simply a LocationId, and LocationTypeId.

Institution and Building both get their Ids from the Location table in a one to one relationship, and the Institution table has a one to many relationship with the Building table.

I am trying to return all location records for an institution and all of its children. The following query returns what I need except that it is missing the parent Institution location record.

```
var query = dc.Locations.SelectMany(l => l.Institutions, (loc, inst) => new { loc, inst })
                        .SelectMany(i => i.inst.Buildings, (locInst, bld) => bld.Location );
```

How can I include the parent along  with the children?

[image: ERD with relevant columns]

**UPDATE:**

I can get the records I want if I use a union on the original location query, but I am still wondering if this is the best solution. Here is the code with the Union.

```
IQueryable<Location> locations = dc.Locations;

locations.SelectMany(l => l.Institutions, (loc, inst) => new { loc, inst })
         .SelectMany(i => i.inst.Buildings, (locInst, bld) => bld.Location)
         .Union(locations);
```

Comment: Can you post the entity classes? At least enough to show how they relate to one another?

Comment: @DanNixon I have added an image of the entity classes with the relevant columns

Comment: It might be better to use `Concat` instead of `Union` unless you actually do what distinct values and not simply a concatenation.  While I don't know with certain, I believe `Concat` would map to a `Union All` in SQL which would be more performant.

Comment: @erdomke You are correct, `Concat` does indeed map to a `Union All` in SQL, however, in my case I do want the distinct values.

Answer (score 6):

Well that's a tricky question, I don't think it can get better then that, although if you want some sort of ordering like 1st the institution location then the Institutions Buildings Locations you can do this:

```
locations.SelectMany(l => l.Institutions, (loc, inst) => new { loc, inst })
         .SelectMany(i => i.inst.Buildings.Union(new List<Building> { new Building { Location = i.loc } }), (locInst, bld) => bld.Location);
```

But the code doesn't get any cleaner from here, your solutions is pretty straight forward and it gets the job done.

This will affect performance and will consume more memory (if it matters) however if this is what you're looking for, I hope it helped. (Because of the order that the Locations are stored)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
        var t = from p in allParents
                from c in p.Children
                select new { Parent = p, Child = c };
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.